# How to get two date fields greater than today and skip nil fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, mongoid3

How to query two date fields to get documents contains existing `:once_at` and `:start_at` greater than today and skip documents if this fields are nil? Wherein `:once_at` and `:start_at` always occur individually. In my example second query with `all_of` returns no results, in code presended below unfortunately gives all documents also this with `:start_at` and `:once_at` are nil.

```
scope :upcoming, -> { any_of(:once_at.ne => nil, :start_at.ne => nil).any_of(:once_at.gte => Date.today, :start_at.gte => Date.today) }
```

**SOLVED:**

In terminal I can see that actual query get also `:start_at => nil`.
I recently started to use scopes and just realized that default_scope has option to get documents with `:start_at => nil`, so I'm discovered that without default_scope query is working as excepted. I'm sorry for this question.

Comment: Please update your question with all the conditions that needs to be satisfied?

Comment: I developed my question.

Comment: Did you check my updated answer?

Comment: Yes. I give you +1 for engagement.

Answer (score 1):

When you use any_of, it will choose even the ones with nil values. Try this

```
scope :upcoming, -> { where(:once_at.gte => Date.today.beginning_of_day, :start_at.gte => Date.today.beginning_of_day) }
```

Comment: This also returns empty results, not all `:once_at` and `:start_at` are defined, so I need `:$or` between, but `:$or` returns all documents. If I'm trying `:$and` between whether nil query it gets results only for first field.

Comment: This will return all collections for which both the date fields are present and they are greater than or equal to today. For or condition, check my updated answer.

Comment: This second solution gets again all docs also this with nils for date fields :(

Comment: If it is possible I want to get only fields with defined :once_at and :start_at and greater than today and skip documents that one of these fields are nil.

Comment: May be you dont get any records, because you dont have any greater than toda. I have updated my query.